# mouse hover effect on image

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: before mouse hover on the image]

[image: after mouse hover on the image]

initially image only visible and the buttons are hide back of image. On image mouse hover the image going little top and buttons will come on bottom of image.
but how to hide the buttons back in image??

before mouse hover the image  only visible after mouse hover on image messup and visible the buttons. i tried like this but not getting, here snippet for reference (http://www.olleep.com/) i m trying to do same

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#textbox').mouseenter(function() {
        $('#textbox').animate({
        'marginTop' : "-=30px" //moves up
        });
    });
    $('#textbox').mouseleave(function() {
        $('#textbox').animate({
        'marginTop' : "+=30px" //moves up
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.container{

       margin:50px;
        }
    #textbox{
        position:relative;
            width:300px;
           
    }
    #text{
      position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
         z-index:1;
        background-color:#282727;
        text-align:center;
        padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div id="textbox">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/9hr2mlL.png" width="300px">
<div id="text">
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-md">MORE INFO</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-md">BOOK NOW</button></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: try setting height for the container and overflow hidden for it. So that initially only the image will be visible. On mouse over image moves up and buttons will be visible

Comment: There is [no need](http://needsmorejquery.com/) for jQuery here, this can be done with CSS alone. You might want to check out the [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) pseudo-class.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with CSS alone, still with adding hover effects, then using `transform:translateY` to toggle these on screen:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
}
.buttons{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;background:dimgray;
  font-size:0;height:40px;
    transition:all 0.4s;
    transform:translateY(100%);
  }
.buttons button{
  width:40%;margin:5%;font-size:15px;

  }
.wrapper img{  transition:all 0.4s;}

.wrapper:hover .buttons{
  transform:translateY(0);
  }
.wrapper:hover img{
    transform:translateY(-35px);
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9hr2mlL.png" />
  <div class="buttons">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to do that. Try `:hover`, check below example.

```css
.container {
  margin: 50px;
}
#textbox {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}
#text {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #282727;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  display: none;
}
#textbox:hover #text {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div id="textbox">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9hr2mlL.png" width="300px">
    <div id="text">
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-md">MORE INFO</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-md">BOOK NOW</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not like this Pugazh. image wil go top [see this ](http://www.olleep.com/) for reference

Answer (score 0):

Add `$('#text').show();` and `$('#text').hide();`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#textbox').mouseenter(function() {
        $('#text').show();
        $('#textbox').animate({
        'marginTop' : "-=30px" //moves up
        });
    });
    $('#textbox').mouseleave(function() {
        $('#text').hide();
        $('#textbox').animate({
        'marginTop' : "+=30px" //moves up
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.container{

       margin:50px;
        }
    #textbox{
        position:relative;
            width:300px;
           
    }
    #text{
      position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
         z-index:1;
        background-color:#282727;
        text-align:center;
        padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div id="textbox">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/9hr2mlL.png" width="300px">
<div id="text">
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-md">MORE INFO</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-md">BOOK NOW</button></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple `.hide()` and `.show()`

Check this
http://codepen.io/vigneshvdm/pen/PNLJKL