# Website slide up animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Hello so i have this css code that lets the text appear as you hover over their titles, but i think an animation going up then having the text appear is an even better effect.

THIS IS THE MAIN CODE:

```
<div class="page" id="proj-dev">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <blockquote class="col-md-4" id="sw-web">
          <div class="quote">
            <span class="intro">Software and Web Development</span>
            <span class="more"> We create software applications that solve complex business problems without giving up on user experience. From application architecture and database design through application development and deployment, we take care of all aspects of developing an enterprise level software application.</span>
          </div>
        </blockquote>

        <blockquote class="col-md-4" id="game-dev">
          <div class="quote">
            <span class="intro">Game Development</span>
            <span class="more">In addition to software & web developments, the team is also focused on distributing aggregated games, developing games and customer applications, rebranding and porting. Our experienced team strive to deliver games that push the edges of the medium through gameplay, art, and pie.</span>
          </div>
        </blockquote>

        <blockquote class="col-md-4" id="art-design">
          <div class="quote">
            <span class="intro">Arts and Designs</span>
            <span class="more">Our graphic design division delivers compelling and inspired print materials to promote your communication efforts. We strive to provide you with a visually consistent, cohesive image. We ensure that your users can easily learn and accomplish basic tasks the first time they encounter the design.</span>
          </div>
        </blockquote> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

THIS IS MY CSS FILE

```
#proj-dev {
  padding: 0;
}

#proj-dev h2 {
  display: none;
}

#proj-dev blockquote {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-left: none;
  min-height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

#proj-dev blockquote .quote {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
  padding: 20px 5%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width:400px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-radius: 0 50px 0 0;
}

#proj-dev #sw-web {
  background:url(../images/dummy.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

#proj-dev #game-dev {
  background:url(../images/dummy.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

#proj-dev #art-design {
  background:url(../images/dummy.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

#proj-dev .quote {
  font-size:20px;
  line-height: 110%;
  font-weight: 400;
}


#proj-dev .quote .more, #proj-dev .customer {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
}


#proj-dev .quote:hover .more {
  font-weight: 100;
  display: block;
  font-size:18px;
  line-height: 120%;
}

#proj-dev .quote:hover .customer {
  display: block;
  font-size: .7em;
  text-align: right;
}
```

[image: Animation Going Up Appears Here]

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: You may be able to alter [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37160006/3436942) to suit your requirements.

Comment: my question is how do make an animation sliding up then the text appears on my website